# Firebase error: CANCELLED: Call cancelled at Object.callErrorFromStatus

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

The error I get looks something like this:

```
Error: 1 CANCELLED: Call cancelled
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:327:49)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:130:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

The code line that gives this error is:

```
const sampleFn = async () => {
try {
      const indices = generateRandomArrayOfN(size, totalSize); // build an array of length (size) with random non repeating numbers between 0 and totalSize
      const docs = await Promise.all(indices.map((i: number) => dbUserRef.offset(i).limit(1).get()));
      for (const doc of docs) {
         if (!doc) continue;
         const userId = doc.docs[0].id;
         const userData = doc.docs[0]?.data();
         if (!userData) continue;
      
         await sendEmail(userData, template); // send some email to user using some template
         console.log(`Email triggered for ${userId}: ${userData.firstName}`);
      }
   } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", err);
   }
}
```

The above snippet was created to fetch random documents from a collection whose total number of documents is totalSize.

For the fact sometimes the Promise.all may be failing because of 1 document but in that case I need to keep the function alive and just fail that single document.

Any ideas on how to resolve this.

During some execution it works fine but other times it's this error.

Comment: Without seeing the full function code it is difficult to say what is causing the error. Can you add the full function code?